# Why can't I call a method when clicking on this span text?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using Vue 3 I am trying to call the `handleViewAuditClick` method when someone clicks the `span`.

I have added `@click="handleViewAuditClick"` event to the `span` text but clicking the text does not call the method.

If I change it so the text is wrapped in a `div` instead that works. Although I have no idea why that works. Using a `div` is also not a good solution for me because it changes the text to be multi-lined which I don't want.

So how do I call the `handleViewAuditClick` when clicking the `span` text?

```Vue
<template>
  <v-alert-banner design="positive">
    New audit is ready.
    <span @click="handleViewAuditClick">
      Click here to view.
    </span>
  </v-alert-banner>
</template>

<script setup>
import VAlertBanner from 'src/components/VAlertBanner.vue';
const handleViewAuditClick = () => {
  console.log('clicked');
};
</script>
```

And this is what the child `v-alert-banner` component looks like:

```Vue
<template>
  <q-banner dense rounded :class="classValue" class="full-width">
    <template #avatar>
      <q-icon :name="iconNameValue" size="sm" />
    </template>
    <slot></slot>
  </q-banner>
</template>
```

Comment: First guess is that there is an element overlaying the span. If you make it an `<a>` or give the span a `:hover`, does it detect when you hover over it?

Comment: You are correct that it is not detected when I hover, so I guess that is progress, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Ok actually that helped! There was a canvas element in front, so I changed the `z-index` and now it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @moritz-ringer in the comments, there was a problem with an element overlaying the span.

I did a browser inspection to find the offending element and gave it `z-index: -1` which solved the problem.